# How to read code from Arduino Uno to Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-uno, c, sketch, debugging, code-optimization

we can upload a code into Arduino UNO from our computers, but how about reading code? Can we read and get C codes from compiled codes from Arduino hardwares? My second question is that will we read these compiled codes on Arduino ZERO's debug port, which will be a new product for us as developers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can we read and get C codes from compiled codes from Arduino hardwares?

While it is possible, even trivial, to disassemble machine code, it is very difficult to convert the assembly code into a higher-level language, and essentially impossible to turn it back into an exact copy of the source code it came from. There simply isn't enough information in the machine code to do so.

> My second question is that will we read these compiled codes on Arduino ZERO's debug port, which will be a new product for us as developers?

The debug port will work in tandem with appropriate software that will already have access to the source code, so this is not a method for conversion either.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to get the code in readable C. It would be in Machine code.